# DocuSign API Payments - Pass Invoice Number to Authorize.Net

Tags: docusignapi, authorize.net

I'm successfully using the DocuSign REST API to create an envelope with a payment connected to my Authorize.Net sandbox account. I'm testing this out in the DocuSign sandbox and it is all working well so far - the Payment prompt appears and I can enter the payment details and this appears in my Authorize.Net account as well.

I'm now wanting to set the Invoice Number that appears in Authorize.Net with a value from my DocuSign Envelope but can't work out if this is even possible yet. Here's what I'm talking about in Authorize.Net:

[image]

You can see that the Invoice Number for my test payment is empty. Is it possible to set this as one of the envelope parameters for the Payment? I've tried setting values for the following in my Formula Tab under paymentDetails:

```
amountReference
description
itemCode
name
```

but can't see this when I view the transaction in the Authorize.Net portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to write directly to the Invoice# field in Authorize.net. I have written an enhancement request. You can track it as "PYMT-3821 Enhancement- Payments need way to write invoice number in Authorize.net."

A possible workaround: You can write the Invoice# into the description field, using customMetaData and customMetadataRequired as follows.

JSON:

```
"paymentDetails": {
    "allowedPaymentMethods": [
        "CreditCard",
        "BankAccount"
        ],
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "customMetadata": "Invoice# 12345",
    "customMetadataRequired": true,
    "gatewayAccountId": "11d6dc32-73e3-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "gatewayDisplayName": "Authorize.Net",
    "gatewayName": "AuthorizeDotNet",
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "amountReference": "NumberTab_1",
            "description": "description",
            "name": "Harmonica"
        }
    ],
    "status": "new"
},
```